# Python 3.10 datetime strptime not picking up time zone?

Tags: python-3.x, timezone, python-datetime, strptime

I have a timestamp embedded in some JSON data as a string, for ease of inspection and modification.  An example looks like this:

```
        "debug_time": 1670238819.9747384,
        "last_saved": "2022-12-05 11:13:39.974725 UTC",
```

When loaded back in, I need to convert it back to a float for comparison against time.time() and similar things, however, I can't seem to find the magic incantations to have it restore the correct value.

In restoring the JSON data, I attempt to convert the string to a float via strptime() like this:

`loaded_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(obj.last_saved, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z')`

This does restore the timestamp to a valid datetime object, however calling `.tzname()` results in None, and my attempts to use `loaded_time.replace(tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('UTC'))` have not yielded any useful results.

In short, emitting `loaded_time.timestamp()` yields `1670267619.974725`, which is 8 hours ahead of what it should be.  I've tried using `.astimezone()`, in various permutations, but can't find a way to correctly have it convert to the client's local time.

I even tried to hard-code in my own time zone `US/Pacific` but it stubbornly refuses to give me that original debug_time value back.

This doesn't seem like it should be a difficult problem, but clearly I'm misunderstanding something about how python 3's time handling works.  Any ideas are welcome!

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I see your side:
you wanna keep timezone on timestamp or similar like that.

1. When you are using timestamp you have to convert timezone definitely any timezone that frontside also knows it. Becouse integer cannot keep timezones UTC its good fit for that.
2. replacing cannot help you, be careful to use it. replace only replace timezone not time

Solution:

```
import datetime
import pytz
timestamped_date = loaded_date.astimezone(pytz.utc).timestamp()
```

Comment: Because...? Please see [answer]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).